# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: エラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rails s すると、以下のようなエラーが出ます。
bundle installは通っています。  
エラーの原因、もしくは解決策等分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えて下さい。

```
    geshi@localhost:(master) $ rails s   [/Users/geshi/sample]
    /Users/geshi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/geshi in PATH, mode 040777
    /Users/geshi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:289: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/geshi in PATH, mode 040777
    /Users/geshi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:289: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/geshi in PATH, mode 040777
    dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2v82V821AddGCPrologueCallbackEPFvNS_6GCTypeENS_15GCCallbackFlagsEES1_
      Referenced from: /Users/geshi/wellness_survey/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.1/v8/init.bundle
      Expected in: flat namespace

    dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2v82V821AddGCPrologueCallbackEPFvNS_6GCTypeENS_15GCCallbackFlagsEES1_
      Referenced from: /Users/geshi/wellness_survey/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.1/v8/init.bundle
      Expected in: flat namespace

    zsh: trace trap  rails s
```

環境

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]  
Rails 4.2.0  
OS X Version 10.11.3
```

Gemfileです。

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    #ruby '2.2.3'


    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    #gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'mysql2'
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.1'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    # jquery-ui
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
    # Datetime picker
    gem 'jquery-datetimepicker-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    #gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

    gem 'devise'
    # OmniAuth is a flexible authentication system utilizing Rack middleware.
    gem 'omniauth'
    gem 'omniauth-oauth2'

    # manage environment specific Rails settings in an easy and usable manner
    gem 'rails_config'

    # Use pry instead of irb in console
    gem 'pry-rails'

    # introduce decorator pattern
    gem 'draper', '~> 1.3'

    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

    # Use unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

    # Use debugger
    # gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

    # Debug
    gem 'tapp'
    gem 'awesome_print'

    # paginator
    gem 'kaminari'

    gem 'roo'

    # レコードを線形リストとして扱う
    gem 'acts_as_list'

    group :development, :staging, :staging_demo do
      gem 'better_errors'
      gem 'binding_of_caller'
      gem 'hirb'
      gem 'hirb-unicode'
      gem 'peek'
      gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
      gem 'meta_request'
    end

    group :development, :staging, :staging_demo, :test do
      gem 'grape-swagger'
      gem 'grape-swagger-ui'
      gem 'grape-swagger-rails'
    end

    # Use unicorn as the app server
    gem 'unicorn'

    group :development do
      # Generate ER-Diagram
      gem 'rails-erd', github: 'ready4god2513/rails-erd', branch: 'rails-4.2-support-fix'
      gem 'quiet_assets'
      gem 'bullet'
      gem 'guard-livereload'

      # Use Capistrano for deployment
      gem 'capistrano', '3.3.3'
      gem 'capistrano-rails'
      gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: "capistrano/rbenv"
      gem 'capistrano-bundler'
      gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
      gem 'capistrano-faster-assets'
      gem 'hub'
      gem 'letter_opener_web'
      gem 'annotate'
    end

    # rspec test gems
    group :development, :test do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '~>3.1'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails'
      gem 'guard-rspec'
      gem 'database_cleaner'
      gem 'pry-byebug'
      gem 'spring', '1.2.0'
      gem 'spring-commands-rspec'

      # DSL for E2E test
      gem 'capybara'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'webmock'
      gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.9.0', require: false
      gem 'json_expressions'
    end

    gem 'seed-fu', '~> 2.3'

    gem 'responders'

    # Utility
    gem 'action_args'
    gem 'rails_autolink'

    #html to pdf
    gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-11'
    gem 'wicked_pdf'

    # for stress_check pdf at 12/5
    gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'

    #pdf report
    gem 'thinreports-rails'

    #for xls
    gem 'spreadsheet'

    gem 'rails-i18n'
    gem 'i18n-js', '>= 3.0.0.rc11'

    # bootstrap
    gem 'bootstrap-sass'

    # it enable to use active record in delayed_job
    gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
    gem 'daemons'

    gem 'newrelic_rpm'

    # Errbit
     gem 'airbrake'

    # cron管理
     gem 'whenever', :require => false

    # to use bulk insert
    gem 'activerecord-import'

    # simple HTTP and REST client for Ruby
    gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.7.3'
    # HttpRequest
    gem 'httparty'

    # API DSL
    gem 'grape'
    gem 'rabl'
    gem 'grape-rabl'
    # A fast JSON parser and Object marshaller as a Ruby gem.
    gem 'oj'
    # device check
    gem 'jpmobile'
    # For managing roles
    gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

    # Retry specified test cases when they fail
    gem 'rspec-retry'

    # slim
    gem 'slim-rails'
    gem 'html2slim'

    # compass
    gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.4'
    gem 'modernizr-rails'

    # font-awesome
    gem 'font-awesome-rails'

    # For business time
    gem "business_time"

    # state machines
    gem 'aasm'

    # dummy data
    gem 'faker'
    # dummy data for japanese
    gem 'faker-japanese'

    gem 'react-rails'

    # Kill the unicorn workers based on the requests and consumed memories
    # Read more: https://github.com/kzk/unicorn-worker-killer
    gem 'unicorn-worker-killer'
```

Comment: rootlessは切ってますか？El Capitanでは"DYLD_"から始まる環境変数をサブシェルに持ち越さないようになっており、アプリケーションがそれに依存している可能性があります。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで仰っている通り、rootlessを切っていないため問題が発生する可能性があります。
rootlessを切っていない場合は以下の記事を参考にしてみてください。

http://applech2.com/archives/46435268.html